# Giving address in a sound or video clip

Tags: phrase-request

How do you give an address in a sound or video clip?
For example, how do you refer to 2:34? minute 2 and second 34?

I tried some google hacks but didn't work for me. Dictionary can't help either. Thanks.

Comment: _At the 2:34 mark_ is one idiomatic way to write this. The phrase `2:34 mark` can be pronounced as "2-minute, 34-second mark"; it could also be pronounced as "two thirty-four".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're looking for, you would say "at two minutes and 34 seconds" or just "at two minutes 34 seconds." If there were a series of these, you could abbreviate it to just "at two thirty-four." (Even without the series, saying "at two thirty-four we see..." is pretty clear by context.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Allow me expand the question a bit: Which of the prepositions would you use here: "...(at?) 2:34 (into/in) the video/recording, the chimpanzee can be heard..."? I know I could skip the part with "(into/in) the video/recording" and safely use *at*, but I'm not so sure when I include it. Is there a difference between *in* and *into* in that context? I've also sometimes heard people using *mark* there somewhere, for example "...at (the) 10-minute mark, a loud noise...", is that what you might say in that context?

Comment: @userr2684291 - Please don't expand your question in the comment below an answer. You need to do two things: (1) Use the edit button to put this information into your original question, and (2) Spend a little bit more time composing your next question such that you won't need to "expand" it in comments.

Comment: @J.R. Unfortunately it's not my question, and it's really closely related in that I'm merely asking for the preposition usage after/before the phrase. Furthermore, the question remains the same because it asks how to reference a certain timestamp in the recording, and the difference (between *in* and *into*) probably isn't big, and would be resolved with two (respective) example contexts, all of which falls under the same question.

Comment: @userr2684291 - Given that this is an English forum, I think the preposition question is the more interesting question, and the one that would be of more potential benefit to future visitors.

Comment: @userr2684291 Agree with J.R. that this is probably better folded into the original question. But: though I probably wouldn't say it, "at the 10 minute mark" sounds perfectly fine. "In" sounds more natural to me, but if I heard somebody say "into" I wouldn't think the person is a non-native speaker.